# Footer DIV keeps jumping to top of page

Tags: css, html, footer

I am developing a small site:

http://www.designbyantony.com/David%20Quigley%20www/index.html

(It's within a folder of my own site on my server)
I would like the footer div to follow on from the content at the end of each page ie: NOT to stick to the bottom of the viewport. I have managed this on all pages except it isnt working on the homepage - as per link above. I have spent a good day trying to fiddle with over:hidden etc but I'm not having any luck. I've a feeling it's something to do with the fact that the homepage uses a fullscreen image.

Comment: i am not sure if i got the footer "not stick" at the bottom. it seems like its already sticked at the bottom for all the other pages

Comment: also why dont you set the background of the page to that picture in css?

Answer (score 1):

Bring the contents outside `#header` you are missing `</div>` after header. 
Remove `position: fixed;` from `#homepage_content` add `z-index:-1` to `#bg`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i know what you are looking for.

1. Move the #homepage_content outside of the #header by removing the `</div>` after `<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->`. Instead add a `</div>` just before the first clear div.
2. Change the css code of #homepage_content to position: relative; or just remove the position: fixed.
3. I think you are looking for a transparent background color of the #homepage_content, right? To do this you must remove the bakcground-color of #homepage_wrapper and instead put white background-color on the #header div.

Hope it fixes it.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your help, really appreciated. This seems to have fixed it. Do you think it lookss okay. I was a bit concerned that the footer creates scrollbars when the viewport comes down in size. What do you reckon? Woudl it be better to fix the footer to the bottom of the viewport for the homepage only?

Answer (score 0):

i have replicated your html in jsfiddle. and set the background in css `background: url`.
footer seems to be in the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/hDkQC/